# How do I configure an Air application to reference an external configuration file?

Tags: apache-flex, configuration, air

I'd like to reference an external configuration (e.g., *.ini) file that will allow me to set configuration variables for each deployment of my Air application.  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any information on the best way to approach this problem.

With that being said, does anyone have any advice on how to make this happen?

Comment: Exactly the question I was looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the implementation of the small xml idea:

```
var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath( "config.xml" );
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();

stream.open( file, FileMode.READ );
config = new XML( stream.readUTFBytes( stream.bytesAvailable ));
stream.close();
```

Just place the config.xml file in your src directory, it will appear in the installed directory when the release package gets installed. I made config a public var on my main application, so I can just do Application.application.config.someOption from anywhere in my project.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if there is an air centric way of making this happen. I haven't found any good class i the api docs. 
If you got a lot of configuration options there might be an idea to look for an existing library that can help you. But if you just need to store some simple settings i would just create a small xml file and parse it with E4X.

It might be possible to jam it inside the [application descriptor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5e5e-7fff.html) but it doesn't feel like a good solution if you want someone to manually change some settings.

Comment: I think we're on the right track with the XML file. How would I reference it from within my app?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest and simplest way is to use [ticlib](http://code.google.com/p/ticlib/) SimpleConfiguration, check [this blog post](http://hemocoid.blogspot.com/2011/05/creating-keep-login-in-adobe-flexair.html). because it based on sharedobject it can be used both in FLEX or AIR application.